# VS2013 ultimate installation failed issue

Tags: windows-8.1, installation, visual-studio-2013

I am getting following error while trying to install VS2013 Ultimate.

[image]

I did googling a lot but didn't find anything.Do I need to install something else before installing VS2013 and if so where can I find that software.
Windows OS: 8.1 64-bit

Thanks

Comment: looks like there has been extensive work on this issue here at StackOverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19444718/visual-studio-2013-rtm-setup-failed-the-form-specified-for-the-subject-is-not

Comment: I have gone through this link already but due to company policies I can not go the web to install VS2013

Comment: ask this in the MSDN forum and share the setup logs: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vssetup/threads

Comment: I tried again and this time its run to 50% and after that I got following error:
fatal error during installation

Comment: Fatal error during installation.

Comment: again, ask it in the official MSDN forum and provide the setup logs. they can help you better